# Shifting tensor over dimension

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Lets say I have a tensor of A of shape [batch_size X length X 1024]
I want to do the following :
for the i element in the batch i want to shift the (embedding 1024) of all 'length' elements embedding by their position .
for example the vector A[0 , 0 , : ] should stay the same, and A[0 , 1 , :] should be shifted (or rolled) by 1 , and A[0 , 15 , :] should be shifted by 15.
this is for all the elements in the batch.
so far i did it with for loops, but its not efficient 
below is my code with for loops :

```
    x = # [batchsize , length , 1024]
    new_embedding = []
    llist = []
    batch_size = x.shape[0]
    seq_len    = x.shape[1]
    for sample in range(batch_size):
     for token in range(seq_len):
      orig = x[sample , token , : ]
      new_embedding.append(torch.roll(orig , token , 0))
     llist.append(torch.stack(new_embedding , 0))
     new_embedding = []
    x = torch.stack(llist , 0)
```